# Give name to PDF in Spring Controller without using @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have Spring Controller, on calling its Request mapping .I am generating PDF file.But problem is that
Generated PDF has name same as the Request mapping Name.

Here I know that we can use @PathVariable to give name.But I don't want To use It.

Example :

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/pdfDownload" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void pdfDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        //Logic OF generating PDF file

    // set response
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Mypdf12345.pdf");

}
```

Here,
My generated PDF file has name pdfDownload.But i want it as Mypdf12345.pdf.
I don't want to use @PathVariable

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: You want to pass in the pdf name with the request?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got my answer.
Earlier problem is that I was using response's outputstream for writing the PDF document.
Hence, now i am writing PDF document to ByteArrayOutputStream and after completing the writing,i am writing that stream to responses's outputsteram.

e.g.

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/pdfDownload" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void pdfDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

      //using bytearrayoutputstream instead of response outputstream,
      ByteArrayOutputStream  out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


        //Logic OF generating PDF file

    // set response
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=Mypdf12345.pdf");

    //transferring that stream to response output stream
    out.writeTo(response.getOutputStream());

}
```

that's it.
Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");    
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Mypdf12345.pdf");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way

```
response.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Mypdf12345.pdf");
```